# Delete Duplicate Items In SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a list which has thousands of records and I need them to be unique.  I found a PowerShell script online that will work if I only have 1 unique column.  However, I have to group by 2 columns and I can't figure out how to make it work.

For example, if I have this data in a SP list, only if both columns are duplicates should the items be removed.

```
Title     Carrier
1         Carrier1
1         Carrier1     *Remove This One
12        Carrier1
12        Carrier2
100       Carrier1 
100       Carrier1     *Remove This One
100       Carrier2
```

Here is the code sample I found online that will work for 1 column, but not for 2.

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$ListName = "DuplicateTest"

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://MyVM/sites/TestSite"
$list = $web.Lists[$ListName]

$AllDuplicates = $list.Items.GetDataTable() | Group-Object Title | where {$_.count -gt 1}
$count = 1
$max = $AllDuplicates.Count
foreach($duplicate in $AllDuplicates) 
{ 
    $duplicate.group | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$list.Items.DeleteItemById($_.ID)} 
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($count / $max * 100) -Activity "$count duplicates removed" -Status "In Progress" 
    $count++ 
}
```

Comment: Figured it out, 

    Group-Object Title, Carrier

Simple but effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you'd probably want to use `Select-Object` with the `-Unique` and `-Property` parameters.

```
$Deduped$list.Items.GetDataTable() | Select-Object -Property Title, Carrier -Unique;
```